# ValidationError (Invalid Date) when importing a CSV to a Data Extension with a Date type field

Tags: marketing-cloud, date, import, data-views, data-import-wizard

**I have extracted the _open Data View** from an old instance **and tried to import the 139K CSV records into a Data Extension in the new instance**.

However, I got a **problem with the "EventDate" field when trying to import the CSV file into the Data Extension**: 19K out of the 139K had a **"Invalid Date" Validation Error**:

Results:

```
Inserted: 119564
```

ValidationErrors:

```
Invalid Date: 19764
```

**I could import successfully the 139K records** into a similar Data Extension **where the DateEvent field was a Text type** instead of a Date type. **But I need to have all the records with a Date type for the EventDate field**.

I don´t understand why this is happening. All the records should have a valid Date since they were imported directly from the Data View.

**What could I do to get all the records imported into a Data Extension with a Date type EventDate?**

Thanks, 
Javi

Answer (score 1):

Check the date format in the file. I bet they're in some specific format and you're selecting another when importing. The ones that got to import successfully were those whose format Marketing Cloud was able to parse: if you have 01-06-2020, it could be June 1st or January 6th, but both are valid dates (they import fine); but if you have 06-13-2020 in your file and you selected "Spanish (Spain)" date format, it'll fail, since there's no such a month as 13.

Check this out: http://help.marketingcloud.com/contentassets/07cc53e235984271b7f0d12c02e1a5d8/dateformats_bylocale.txt

Regards,

AGMH.